# Mediawiki: changePassword.php can't authenticate mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, change-password

I'm trying to use the changePassword.php maintenance script provided by mediawiki:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ChangePassword.php
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords

However, when I try to run

```
php changePassword.php --user=aaaa --password=xxxx
```

I simply get

```
Error connecting to MySQL: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: YES)
```

I'm pretty sure my root password is the same as MySQL one. would there be any other reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: your system accounts have absolutely no relationship with mysql accounts, other than maybe you coincidentally set them to be the same. mysql will not use your system password.

Comment: What password did you enter? The parameter is the new password for the *user*. The script uses whatever DB user and password configured in LocalSettings.php to access the database; are you sure you are using the correct user? On many wikis, the user with relevant permissions is apache or www-data.

Comment: can you browse the site properly? this maintenance script use the db credentials mentioned in ` LocalSettings.php` so if you can browse the site properly the script should work.